# CSV Export Decimal Points added

Tags: java, excel, groovy

My application has three formats (CSV, xls, and json) in which data can be exported to.  Within the data there are percentage values that range from whole numbers to decimal values; the decimal values only have tenths places.  The issue occurs when exporting to CSV it appends a zero digit to the end of decimal values (i.e. 25.1% becomes 25.10%; 25% remains 25%).  It does not occur when exporting to xls.  Is there something that can be done to prevent the percentage values from adding a trailing zero for decimal values when exporting to CSV?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code, that shows the problem.

Comment: There isn't an issue in the code itself.  It's when you open the csv file in excel it automatically changes it to 2 decimal points.

Comment: Have you examined the csv file using a **text editor** and confirmed that the trailing zero is absent?

Comment: I have.  The trailing zero is absent.

Comment: It is a formatting issue within Excel.  The value stored is numeric and would not have the trailing zero.  In order for Excel to display the result to only one decimal, you could either specify the column to be TEXT at the time of import, or format that column as percentage with one decimal place.

Comment: You may also adjust your default percentage style to have only a single decimal (right click on the Percent under the Styles tab on the Home ribbon, and select Modify)

Comment: I appreciate all of the responses.  It doesn't seem possible to define the number of decimal values when exporting to CSV and opening in excel.  This is something defined in Excel itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to define the number of decimal values when exporting to a comma separated values format.  This became clear when I looked at the raw values in Windows Notepad and then excel.  The notepad version has 1.0% while when opened in Excel it appeared as 1.00%.

Therefore, it seems that the styles will have to be updated manual within excel itself.

Thanks.